# Getting variable value from external JavaScript file in jQuery $(document).ready(function(){});

Tags: javascript

I have defined on external JavaSsript file which contains one variable such as the following

```
var demo='Hello'".
```

I want to use this variable's value in jQuery's `$(document).ready()` event. How can I accomplish this?

Comment: Any thing u put inside document.ready will become private. So if u want to access some variable inside document, it has to be outside document.ready

Btw. document.ready can simplified $(function({ });

Answer (score 2):

All you have to do is put the external file above your main script:

```
<script src="external.js"></script>
<script>
     // "demo" is accessible here
</script>
```

Script tags load synchronously, so once the second script tag executes, you can be sure the first one has already loaded.

**Edit**

Per the comment, this script works for me:

```
<html>
    <script src="global.js"></script>
    <script type="text/javascript" src="http://code.jquery.com/jquery-2.0.3.js"></script> 
    <script type="text/javascript"> 
        $(document).ready(function() { var x=abc(); alert('hello'+x); }); 
    </script>
</html>
```

Where `global.js` is just:

```
function abc() { var valu='hello'; return valu; }
```

Comment: Hi McGarnagle.This is my script :==<script type="text/javascript" src="global.js"></script> <script type="text/javascript" src="../../Script Library/jquery-1.4.3.min.js"></script> <script type="text/javascript"> $(document).ready(function() { var x=abc(); alert('hello'+x); }); </script> ==This is my externla .js file code:==function abc() { var valu='hello'; return valu; }:But this is not working.please help me

Comment: @Naveen I think there must be some other problem -- your code works for me (see edit above).  Do you see any script errors?

Answer (score 0):

If you have defined that file before the file with the ready event, it should be available providing the scope is correct. ie:

```
<script type="text/javascript" src="scriptwithvalue.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript" src="scriptthatwantsthevalue.js"></script>
```

When I'm passing variables between files, I tend to wrap the logic up in a getter and setter, ie:

**File One**

```
var name = "Dave";

function getName()
{
    return name;
}
```

**File Two**

```
var name = getName();
```

**Edit**

As above, if your Javascript is already in the HTML file, then simply importing the script with the value in it is enough.

Comment: does it really make sense? I guess just importing external js will do for it

Comment: This was assuming that the user is practising [unobtrusive javascript](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Unobtrusive_JavaScript)

Comment: Hi Chris.This is my script :==<script type="text/javascript" src="global.js"></script> <script type="text/javascript" src="../../Script Library/jquery-1.4.3.min.js"></script> <script type="text/javascript"> $(document).ready(function() { var x=abc(); alert('hello'+x); }); </script> ==This is my externla .js file code:==function abc() { var valu='hello'; return valu; }:But this is not working.please help me

Comment: Good lord, edit it into your question please. And are you still having the same problem?